# Catching a Tkinter exception for a missing file

Tags: python, tkinter, file-io, try-catch

I'm writing a Tkinter program that loads some .png images.

Since files can be faulty or non-existent, it is good to use a try-except block.  I'm first checking the file with generic Python.  Then I load the image file into Tkinter if it passes the generic Python try-except block:

```
ok = True
try:
    image_file = open("cat.png")
    image_file.close()
except IOError:
    ok = False

if ok:
    self.image = PhotoImage(file="cat.png")
```

This has to load the image file twice: once for the Python check, and once for Tkinter.  Also, there is no guarantee the Tkinter image load attempt will work.  If the file were arriving over a network, it is possible the file was available for the Python try-except call, but was then suddenly not available for the Tkinter call.

When I intentionally crash the program by making a call to an unavailable file, I get:

```
tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "fakefile.png": no such file or directory
```

This is exactly the error type (file not found) that I am trying to catch inside of Tkinter.  I've hunted around, but I have been unable to find out a way for Tkinter to try-except its own call to: `PhotoImage(...)`.

How can I safely load the PNG?

Comment: How did you manage to get that error message? I am unable to reproduce it with your code.

Comment: @codebeginner some people down vote just because you ask why. Also, this new "welcome thing" seems to be increasing the # of downvotes and decreasing users willingness to comment on why. I would remove the "Thank you" and last sentence "Does anybody have any ..." as this makes it look like a shopping list question and instead just say "How can I load the PNG safely?"

Comment: @JGreenwell You might be right but I think the lack of a [MCVE] and of any attempts to catch errors raised by `PhotoImage` are simpler explanations.

Comment: @goyo I just wadded through like 15 homework dumps so this question was refreshing actually (even if it needed improvement) :)

Comment: @goyo when you replace "cat.png" (an actual file) with "fakefile.png" (a non-existent file), it produces the error i indicated.

Comment: @codebeginner Not for me. `open('fakefile.png')` raises an `IOError` which is catched, `ok` is set to `False`, `PhotoImage` is not called and no errors are printed.

Comment: @goyo.  good point.  what i meant to say is this: don't do the try-except code at all. simply run this line of code on a non-existent file named "fakefile.png": self.image = PhotoImage(file="fakefile.png").  it then produces the error i indicated. the crux of my question was how to do error handling on an image file using tkinter directly.    abamert produced the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to make tkinter try-except its own call; just try-except your call to tkinter:

```
try:
    self.image = PhotoImage(file="cat.png")
except tkinter.TclError:
    # do whatever you wanted to do instead
```

For example:

```
try:
    self.image = PhotoImage(file="cat.png")
except tkinter.TclError:
    self.cat = Label(text="Sorry I have no cat pictures")
else:
    self.cat = Label(image=self.image)
```